# Why is my foreign key constraint not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
/*Create Purchased Products Table*/
create table Purchased_Products
(
School_ID INT not null,
Product_ID INT not null,
Purchased_Product_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) not null,
Quantity INT,
Product_Status VARCHAR(1)

  constraint Purchased_Products_PK PRIMARY KEY (School_ID, Product_ID, Purchased_Product_ID),
  constraint Purchased_Products_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (School_ID) REFERENCES School(School_ID),
  constraint Purchased_Products_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID) REFERENCES Product(Product_ID)
);
```

---

```
create table Credentials
(
Credential_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) not null,
Purchased_Product_ID INT not null,
Username VARCHAR (30),
PPassword VARCHAR (30),
URL VARCHAR (100),
Remote_Username VARCHAR (30),
Remote_Password VARCHAR (30),
Remote_URL VARCHAR (100),
Notes VARCHAR (200),

  constraint Credentials_PK PRIMARY KEY (Credential_ID, Purchased_Product_ID),
  constraint Credentials_FK FOREIGN KEY (Purchased_Product_ID) REFERENCES Purchased_Products(Purchased_Product_ID)

);
```

Ok so I want to create this table, Credentials, but it gives me the error:

Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Purchased_Products' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'Credentials_FK'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

It seems that it would allow me to do this but I cannot think of what I am doing. Maybe I am overlooking something?? Help??!!??

Comment: You need an index or Purchased_Product_ID or set it as a primary key of table Purchased_product

Comment: Erm... is `IDENTITY(1,1)` MySQL? Never some that one, but I know [this one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: @Wrikken Identity(1,1) is valid in MSSQL as well.

Comment: @Aushin: exactly my point. There was an erroneous `mysql` tag (which a_horse_with_no_name removed now), which does _not_ know what `IDENTITY(1,1)` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purchased_Products.Purchased_Product_ID needs to be explicitly UNIQUE or explicitly your primary key in order for it to be the reference column for your foreign key.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IndexName 
ON Purchased_Products(Purchased_Product_ID)
```

Creating the unique index enforces uniqueness on the column (or set of columns if you have more than one column in your index) and SQL will let you use it as a reference for a foreign key.

Comment: In the Purchased_Products table?

Comment: @user1579871 I'll edit the statement into the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not have reputation enough to give you an up vote but you answered my question exactly and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys can only be created on columns with UNIQUE coumns like a primary key or unique index.

Table `Purchased_Products` currently only has one unique constraint, being the compound PK:

```
constraint Purchased_Products_PK 
   PRIMARY KEY (School_ID, Product_ID, Purchased_Product_ID)
```

And table `Credentials` is trying to enforce the foreign key on only one of these columns, viz

```
constraint Credentials_FK 
  FOREIGN KEY (Purchased_Product_ID) 
  REFERENCES Purchased_Products(Purchased_Product_ID)
```

Technically, you would need to repeat all the compound key columns in `Credentials` (i.e. `School_ID`, `Product_ID`, `Purchased_Product_ID`) and create the compound foreign key on these.

However, it seems that something is wrong in your table design - your choice of `Primary Keys` seems unfortunate, e.g. `Purchased_Products` has a candidate for a simple surrogate primary key:

```
Purchased_Product_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) not null
```

Similarly for `Credentials`, given that `Credential_ID` is already unique through the `identity`, there is no need to add `Purchased_Product_ID` to the PK. What you probably want is:

```
Table : Products
Primary Key : ProductId

Table : Purchased_Products
Primary Key : Purchased_Product_ID
Foreign Key : ProductID references Products(ProductId)

Table : Credentials
Primary Key : Credential_ID
Foreign Key : Purchased_Product_ID references Purchased_Products(Purchased_Product_ID)
```

etc.

Comment: I believe he shouldn't have the composite key.  Purchased_Product_ID is already an identity column in a table that stores purchased products.  But I guess that isn't the question, is it?

Comment: Agreed, compound keys are a curse. But OP's PK's are ill advised.